# Can't change visual attributes of edges in R plot.rgexf function

Tags: r, sigma.js

I'm trying to create a graph with R "rgexf" library, using it's plot method for "gexf" objects.
Unfortunately, I can't change any of the visual attributes of edges of the graph - they seem to be stuck at default.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(rgexf)
people <- data.frame(id=1:4, label=c("juan", "pedro", "matthew", "carlos"),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
# Data frame of edges
relations <- data.frame(source=c(1,1,1), 
                    target=c(2,3,4))
# Building gexf graph
mygraph <- write.gexf(nodes=people, edges=relations,
                 edgesVizAtt = list(size = c(1.1,10.1,20.1)))

# Plotting
plot(mygraph)
```

The resulting graph(opens up in my browser (Chrome/Safari) seems to ignore `size` attribute in `edgesVizAtt`.

`plot(mygraph)` uses `sigma.js` library I believe, but I can't find any error.

So here's the question: How do I correctly add visual attributes to edges via `rgexf` library?

Thank you!